# Is timeseries regression imputation alwayse worse than simply dropping the covariates?

Tags: regression, time-series, linear-model, data-imputation

I am working on a timeseries forecast problem using linear regression. My current model is an OLS like $$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1  + \beta_2 x_2  + \epsilon.$$ I have the forward curves on $x_1$ and $x_2$ from other sources (e.g. derived from markets), so I can use the forward values of $x_1^{<t>}$ and $x_2^{<t>}$ to get a prediction on $y^{<t>}$ once I trained the model on the real data. However, the forward curves of $x_1$ and $x_2$ have different lengths, some are $1$ year, others are $6$ months, or less. I want to get the longest forecasts of $y$ possible, and thus I was thinking about using the longer one, say $x_1$, to run a regression to impute  $x_2$. But then I realized this is equivalent to a linear model of $y$ against $x_1$. The model should be also unbiased, since there is only linear transformation taking place. Thus it is worse than a simple OLS of $y$ directly against $x_1$, which has the lowest variance among all unbiased model. I wonder if this reasoning is correct?

And if it is correct, are there any merits to do biased model such as Lasso or Ridge? The procedure is similar: first train the model of $y$ against real $x_1$ and real $x_2$, and then fit $x_2$ against $x_1$ to impute the values of $x_2$ using the forward curves of $x_1$, and finally predict $y$ using $x_1$ and the fitted $\hat{x}_2$. Is it better or worse then just running the model against $x_1$?

Comment: Forward prices are not forecasts of future spot prices.

Comment: @ChrisHaug Yeah you are correct.  I probably should have phrased the terms more precisely. The forward curve I mean is not the spot prices of future contracts but some values derived from the market that give a forecast for the future spot value of the variables